# Sort array according to the search string occurence php

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array, sorting

I want to sort two dimensional array according to the occurrence of the search string in php. i tried to fetch data according to the relevance of search string . i come across match and against but it will work on the MYISAM but my table is in innodb. so plan to sort the array using any sort function but i cant find out anything.

my  search **pressure tes** string array

```
  Array
   (
      [0] => pressure
       [1] => tes
    )
```

My output array which matches the above string with title is

```
 Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => tests.doc
        [link] => http://localhost/test.doc
        [snippet] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => Pressure Testing Your Company
        [link] => http://localhost/Pressure_Testing_Your_Companys.pdf
        [snippet] => Questions used by the CFO against dimensions critical to success
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => pressure.doc
        [link] => http://localhost/pressure.doc
        [snippet] => Templates for services
    )
```

)

In the above array the most relevant array[1] then array[2] and then array[0] should be in this order. i want to sort this array accordingly. **my output should be like below**:

```
 Array
(

[0] => Array
    (
        [title] => Pressure Testing Your Company
        [link] => http://localhost/Pressure_Testing_Your_Companys.pdf
        [snippet] => Questions used by the CFO against dimensions critical to success
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [title] => pressure.doc
        [link] => http://localhost/pressure.doc
        [snippet] => Templates for services
    )
[2] => Array
    (
        [title] => tests.doc
        [link] => http://localhost/test.doc
        [snippet] => 
    )

)
```

please help me!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the example #3, I think that's what you want.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php

Just tested this, it seems to be working :

```
$titles = array();

foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) 
{
    $titles[ $key ] = $value['title'];
} 

array_multisort( $titles, SORT_ASC , $array );
```

I would highly recommend to sort your results in your MySQL query, that would be much better performance wise.